# How can I forward call from Servlet to Jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, java-ee-7

I am sorry to change my entire concept.

I want to forward call from `Servlet` to `Jsp`.While forwarding time I will pass parameters.

Sevlet Program.

```
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    //Creating object to FunctionNames class for calling their functions 
        try {
            FunctionNames FunctionNamesObject=new FunctionNames();
            //calling Method from class object
            List<File> finalListNames=FunctionNamesObject.ListOfFileNames(getServletContext().getRealPath("/copy"),".txt");
            for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < finalListNames.size(); fileIndex++) {
                //Copy and pasting file from SourcePath to destination Path
                FunctionNamesObject.FileMoving(
                                            finalListNames.get(fileIndex),
                                            getServletContext().getRealPath("/Rod"),
                                            "TMapInput.txt"
                                            );
                //.exe file process will be start from here.
                FunctionNamesObject.ExeternalFileProcessing(getServletContext().getRealPath("/Rod"),"ThMapInfratab1-2.exe","TMapInput.txt");
                //Later Rods output files moving from one directory to another function will be added here
                request.setAttribute("Name","ABD");
                request.setAttribute("Password", "DEF");
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/JSPFiles/JspTesting.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response ) ;
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Jsp Code is:

```
<%
   out.print(request.getAttribute("Name"));
   out.print(request.getAttribute("Password"));
 %>
```

If you observe my code, `RequestDispatcher` code is in `for` loop,means For every iteration I want to forward call to `Jsp` file with parameters.

in first iteration, I am getting response from `Jsp` file,but it's not working from second iteration.I am getting the following error.

```
  HTTP Status 500 - Cannot forward after response has been committed
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
PackageName.ClassName.service(ClassName.java:36)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

How can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: What's your actual purpose? You can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: we build an application using `Wolfram Mathematica` I can integrated   my `Mathematica` in `JSP`, finally my `Mathematica` code is in `JSP` file. it fetch values from queryString(from URL).also we have a `.exe` file, using `Java` I can run the `.exe`. Once I run the `.exe` file it gives `.txt` files as a output.After this If I trigger my `Mathematica` Application,It imports `.exe` output files and does some heavy computations and finally some data will be saved in `DB`.

Comment: ... And why do you need to iterate over the files to do this? It really sounds like your architecture is a little broken at the moment.

Comment: When you use `forward` with a `RequestDispatcher`, you're basically telling the container that the resource you're forwarding to should finish handling the request. It should be the last method call in your servlet method (you can't have it in a loop).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for your answer.@Dave you are right My architecture is totally broken.In my Kt that guys mention wrongly.Thanks for your valuable suggestion.Actually I want to implement Queueing for requests.If I get any number of requests at a time, I need to save all in queue and release 1 request at a time.because Every request runs the same `.exe` file.